# Hiding a Window hides the MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got another Window besides my MainWindow in my Application and I override the closing-method like this because I don't want the Window to be fully closed:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

then in the constructor:

```
public Inputwindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Closing += Window_Closing;
}
```

But now if I want to close my MainWindow, it only hides the MainWindow.

Can't figure out, how to get it to work.

Comment: What do you want hide or close?

Comment: I believe that he does not want to dispose the window. The window_closing event where is declared? If this.visibility = visibility.hidden closes the main window means that this is the main window so you declared it in the wrong place.

Comment: @MegaTron In my MainWindow I open another Window, which if I click the Close-button of this new Window, should not be closed. So I implemented the Method above to hide the new Window. But now If i click the Close-button on the MainWindow, it doesn't close the whole Application. It only hides the MainWindow instead.

Comment: @sstan No, MainWindow is a class and Inputwindow is another class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every WPF application has a property called Application.ShutdownMode, which determines when the application actually ends. By default, it is set to OnLastWindowClose, which means that the application won't end until all windows are closed (even if the main window closes). It sounds like you want your application to end when the main window closes even if other windows are not closed, just hidden, which would correspond to the OnMainWindowClose mode. Here is the relevant MSDN documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode(v=vs.110).aspx

To set the property in your xaml, open the App.xaml file and add the ShutdownMode property like this:

```
<Application x:Class="TestClass"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose">       

</Application>
```

Comment: So if I implement a closing method for the MainWindow where I close all other Windows and then close the MainWindow, it would work?

Comment: Yeah, that's one possible approach, but I think it is better to be explicit about this. Since you want the application to shut down when you close the main window, I would recommend you set the ShutdownMode accordingly. I edited my answer with an example of how to set the property in your App.xaml file. Just append the ShutdownMode property to the Application tag in your App.xaml like I did in the example code. Yours should be similar, except you might have added some other properties that I don't have on mine.

Comment: Yeah, setting the property in my App.xaml worked for me! Thank you!